# Radio Button go to another file on Submit

Tags: html, perl

I'm writing a Perl CGI script. My `index` page should display a set of radio buttons in a form and go to another page/file according to the selected button.

I can't figure out the right way to do it.

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "<!DOCTYPE html>";
print "<html>";
print "<body>";
print "<h1> Welcome to Magnum </h1>";
print "<h2> System Check </h2>";
print "<h2> -------------------- </h2>";

print "<form method='post'>";
print "<input type='radio' name='option' value='process' formaction='/home/john/www/process'/ > View My Process<$
print "<input type='radio' name='option' value='calendar'> View Calendar <br>";
print "<input type='radio' name='option' value='location'> View my location coordinates<br> Latitude and Altitud$
print "<input type='radio' name='option' value='users'> View all users connected on my System<br>";
print "<input type='radio' name='option' value='find'> Find a file or Directory<br>";

print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'> <br>";


print "</form>";
print "<h2> -------------------- </h2>";
print "</body>";
print "</html>";
```

It has to be written like this as it's the way we've been taught.
If an answer involves something too different then it won't help,

Comment: Perhaps you could start by explaining what problems you are having? What isn't working how you want it to? The syntax highlighting in your code example clearly shows that something isn't right. Perhaps you could start by fixing those problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some high level code that might help.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Use functions from CGI.pm to make your life easier
use CGI qw[header redirect param];

# Hash containing valid redirection values.
my %valid_redirects = map { $_ => 1 } qw[process calendar location
                                       users find];

# Get the chosen option
my $option = param('option');

# If we've a) got an option and b) it's a valid option
# then redirect to the chosen page.
if ($option and $valid_redirects{$option}) {
  # You'll need to write a redirect_to() subroutine
  print redirect_to("$option.html");
} else {
  # If we don't have a valid redirection option, display the form.
  # You'll need to write an html_form() subroutine
  print header;
  print html_form();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggested solution.

Create a separate subroutine for each of the radio button options.  Create a dispatch table using those subs.  Execute the appropriate dispatch table subroutine based on the form submission.